# If $g(x)$ is the inverse of $f(x)=x^3+2x+4$, evaluate $g(7)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inverse

> Let $g(x)$ be the inverse of the function: $$f(x) = x^3+2x+4$$ Calculate $g(7)$.

I don't know where to begin, since you can't easily find the inverse by switching the $x$ and $y$ around.

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is $f(1)$?

Comment: If $g(7) = c$, then $f(c) = 7$ since $f$ and $g$ are inverses. So, this is equivalent to finding where $f(x) = 7$.

Comment: Thank you both. I had figured that was the way to begin but I wasn't too sure

Comment: *"I had figured that was the way to begin but I wasn't too sure"* ... In the future, be sure to include such figuring (instead of claiming "I don't know where to begin"). Even if you're wrong, this information can help people refine or confirm your thinking, without wasting time (theirs or yours) telling you things you already know or duplicating your effort. (Also ... Very often, "I don't know where to begin" is taken to mean "Do my homework for me", so you don't want to give people the wrong impression.)

Comment: if you really don't know where to begin, try to enter $f$ into an online graphing calculator to see for what value of $t$ does $f(t) = 7$. Perhaps you'll get lucky and it will be an integer (as in this case) or a simple fraction. When in doubt ... cheat. :p

Answer (score 1):

As KM101 commented, need to solve for $f(x)=7$. Since $g(y)$ is the inverse function, we know that whatever x value in $f(x)$ gives 7 is the output of $g(y)$.

$7=x^3+2x+4$

$0=x^3+2x-3$

$0=(x-1)*(x^2+x+3)$

$x=1$ 
There is no value of x that will make $0=(x^2+x+3)$ true so it will just be 1.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** Obviously $f$ is an increasing function since all nonconstant terms have odd degree and positive coefficient, so it is invertible, and if we found $x$ so that $f(x)=7$ then it is the only one. Can you find such an $x$?

Answer (score -1):

f(x)=7

x^3+2x+4=7

x^3+2x-3=0

(x-1)(x^2+x+3)=0

So,x=1is the answer.
Thanks for asking.It was a very good question.